Correct analysis interpretation of unusual study design
The National Audit Projects from the Royal College of Anaesthetists are a series of projects investigating rare complications of anaesthesia. Examples include severe allergic reactions and cardiac arrest. (for anyone wanting read a specific one I'd suggest NAP3 as the simplest)
They use a methodology that I am not familiar with and I am struggling to find a good reference for correct analysis. They try to estimate the frequency of these events and also suggest risk factors for them. The basic idea is:

Measuring the denominator

Perform an "activity survey" - get hospitals to log (anonymously) every case they do over a short period (usually a few days to weeks or thereabout)
Multiply this up to get a denominator for the period of interest


Measuring the numerator

Ask hospitals to report the complications of interest - this phase is over a much longer period (usually many months)



Trying to apply what I already know, obviously this is an observational study; it isn't cross-sectional data and it isn't a case-control study; it looks somewhat similar to a prospective cohort study - we're watching a defined group of people over time and counting events - but with some differences:

There is not a well-defined cohort - we cannot talk about individuals being recruited to this study until they have an event
The "pseudo-cohort" is measured over a short period and then extrapolated to suggest what it might have looked like had we recruited over the time period of interest
Exposure data is only well known for patients who experience an event

This may well be the best data on these events collected during my career and it is widely used in anaesthetic practice so it is important that it is understood correctly.
My questions are:

Does this sort of study have a well-known name? (i.e. what can I search for??)
Are there standard recipes or guidelines for analysing this sort of study?
Are there good methods for accounting for the uncertainties in the denominator data?
Is it reasonable to use standard frequentist techniques for analysis of conventional cohort studies on this sort of data? (important, because this is what they have done!)

EDIT:
My particular concern is:

The initial "activity survey" is cross-sectional data - statistics derived from this have not only a central tendency but also a confidence interval
We then multiply the statistics from this cross-sectional data to consider a longer time period - presumably our confidence intervals for the derived data have increased linearly? (and just as a direct multiple of the scale factor?)
They then use the point estimate produced by (2) as the denominator:

Should we incorporate the confidence intervals produced by (2) and calculate several results using upper & lower 95% CI bounds as well as the central tendency?
Is it valid to create 95% CIs for this "second-order" statistic using standard techniques (i.e. with RelRisk in R)?




The only problem I see is the "fudged" denominator. So it will depend on other factors. What is the goal of the study? What metrics are you trying to obtain. An overall risk factor for anaesthesia? Comparing hospitals for risk? Or comparing procedures? Or? What effect size(s) would you expect to detect? What would be a non-trivial proportion change? Ec...

@jginestet thanks for the reply. I'll update my question - I wrote this questions whilst jiggling a baby to sleep & I think I haven't specified my concerns very well.

@jginestet With regards to your specific point, the primary aim was define an estimate for the overall risk of the adverse event in question. Then they analysed the cohort to try and identify risk factors: i.e. for NAP6 (anaphylaxis): do particular antibiotics cause more problems than others?

@jginestet The other difficulty is, as far as I can see, they haven't published a pre-specified statistical analysis plan so its very difficult to see how much of what they published is the result of enthusiastic reporting of happy coincidence
